# Avoid the slash(/) between Spring RequestMapping

Tags: spring, slash, request-mapping

Consider the following example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/home"})
public class Home {
    @RequestMapping(value = { "", "/" })
    public String index() {
        return "home";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = { "-of-{id}" })
    public String of(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

index() is mapped to '/home' and '/home/' perfectly; but of(id) is mapped to '/home/-of-{id}' when I want it to be mapped to '/home-of-{id}'.

Spring add a slash between '/home' and '-of-{id}' automatically, but I want to eliminate it, any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

When you define a class-level mapping, Spring treats the method-level mappings as additional segments, not as string concatenations. So you can't get the `/home-of-{id}` using the approach you're attempting.

Try getting rid of the class-level `@RequestMapping`, and replace the existing method-level mappings with fully-explicit paths. Put `@RequestMapping("/home-of-{id}")` on `of()`.

If you are going to have lots of `/home/` paths that you want to support (and thus you want to keep the class-level definition in place), just move the `/home-of-{id}` to a separate controller and you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class-level mapping and map each method. When you map a class and methods, they're hierarchical.

(Or create different classes.)